# Show only last login in the SSH welcome message

Tags: bash, ssh, raspberry-pi, openssh

When i log in to my raspberry pi it shows me this message, i like the fact that it shows the last login but the info is too long (also because i log in from mobile devices).

```
Linux RaspberryPi 4.1.11+ #822 PREEMPT Fri Oct 23 16:14:56 BST 2015 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Oct 29 17:00:38 2015 from computer.local
```

It there a possibility to show this instead?

```
Last login: Thu Oct 29 17:00:38 2015 from computer.local
```

Also, show the ip address instead of the resolved name?

I know i can see the auth.log but i wonder if it's possible.

Comment: what distro you are running on the rpi?

Comment: the official raspbian (wheezy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message comes from the standard file `/etc/motd` where the administrator
can put info for people logging in. Simply empty it, eg:

```
sudo sh -c '>/etc/motd'
```

You can get the ip address of a last login with

```
last -i $USER | grep -v 'still logged' | head -1
```

From the comments below: `PrintMotd no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is the default in debian it seems, but has no effect: ssh still shows the /etc/motd file.

Comment: Actually in /etc/ssh/sshd_config PrintMotd is set to no however the message is shown

Comment: ok, but it certainly looks like motd. perhaps something else is printing it?

Comment: Only shows what i've posted

Comment: You can create a file `~/.hushlogin` to suppress some msgs.

Comment: what's the value of `PrintLastLog` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ?

Comment: ~/.hushlogin disables every message. I followed your suggestion and created an empty motd. However i don't understand why it showed the message even when disabled

Comment: PrintLastLog is yes, PrintMotd is no

Comment: about your question about why it was still showing message too if disabled it, i can think only that you forgot to restart sshd ?

Comment: @Matteo I also have `PrintMotd no` by default, and I get the motd printed anyway.

Comment: about your wish to edit Last login message, setting ip address instead of resolved name, (reading this post)[http://serverfault.com/questions/598043/how-do-i-edit-the-ssh-last-login-message#598046] I assume it is not possible in a easy way

Comment: PrintMotd was disabled prior to asking. However @meuh's workaround worked, now it only shows the uname -a output and the last login.

Comment: You can get your ip address with `who am i --ips`.

Comment: Ok, but i was wondering to show the ip in the last login message. However i think i will accept the answer in a few if there are no additional answers. My primary concern was about the motd.

Comment: sorry, of course you want it from last login, and `last -i $USER|grep -v 'still logged'|head -1` seems to show ip addresses.

Comment: @meuh True, but it shows 0.0.0.0 as IP address?

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg I can only assume that the login line shown was not by ssh from a remote machine, as 0.0.0.0 is shown for local logins (e.g. in a terminal). I'm not sure what else could cause this sort of entry.

Comment: I'm using the ssh command to execute commands, again directly using the ssh command. I think that is the root cause.